# Rust ndarray Dot for custom types without Copy

Tags: rust, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra, traits

In `python`'s `NumPy` I can create custom data types with operator overloads and get broadcasted results with linear algebra functions (such as `matmul`, `dot`, `tensordot` etc.)

```py
import numpy as np


class MyType:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a, self.b = a, b

    def __add__(self, other):
        return MyType(a=self.a + other.a, b=self.b + other.b)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return MyType(a=self.a + other.a, b=self.b * other.b)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<{}, {}>".format(self.a, self.b)


arr1 = np.array([MyType("A", 2.0), MyType("B", 3.0)])
arr2 = np.array([MyType("C", 2.0), MyType("D", 4.0)])

>>> arr1 + arr2
[<AC, 4.0> <BD, 7.0>]
>>> arr1 * arr2
[<AC, 4.0> <BD, 12.0>]
>>> arr1.dot(arr2))
<ACBD, 16.0>
```

In `Rust` I can create the same overloads but the `ndarray` crate `Dot` function does not work because `MyType` does not satisfy trait bounds.

```rust
use std::ops;
use ndarray::{arr1};

#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
pub struct MyType {
    a : String,
    b : f64
}

impl ops::Add<MyType> for MyType {
    type Output = MyType;
    fn add(self, other: MyType) -> MyType {
        MyType {a: [self.a, other.a].join(""), b: self.b + other.b}
    }
}

impl ops::Mul<MyType> for MyType {
    type Output = MyType;
    fn mul(self, other: MyType) -> MyType {
        MyType {a: [self.a, other.a].join(""), b: self.b * other.b}
    }
}

fn main() {
    let arr_1 = arr1(&[
        MyType {a: "A".to_string(), b: 2.0}, MyType {a: "B".to_string(), b: 3.0}
    ]);
    let arr_2 = arr1(&[
        MyType {a: "C".to_string(), b: 2.0}, MyType {a: "D".to_string(), b: 4.0}
    ]);
    >>> println!("{:?}", arr_1.clone() + arr_2.clone());
    [MyType { a: "AC", b: 4.0 }, MyType { a: "BD", b: 7.0 }]
    >>> println!("{:?}", arr_1 * arr_2);
    [MyType { a: "AC", b: 4.0 }, MyType { a: "BD", b: 12.0 }]
    >>> println!("{:?}", arr_1.dot(&arr_2));
    error[E0599]: the method `dot` exists for struct `ArrayBase<OwnedRepr<MyType>, Dim<[usize; 1]>>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
}
```

The significant trait bound seems to be `pub trait LinalgScalar: 'static + Copy + Zero + One + Add<Output = Self> + Sub<Output = Self> + Mul<Output = Self> + Div<Output = Self> { }`

I can implement all of these except for `Copy`, since I'm not sure if the attributes of `MyType` can be copied and I don't believe I can permit a static lifetime. Does this mean I need to implement my own specific form of the `Dot` function which will no doubt be much less efficient that the default?

Comment: Consider that the `ndarray` implementation of `dot` is as efficient as it is because it only operates on `Copy` types.

Comment: Understand, but then there might be a case for a solution for implementing it without the `Copy` types that is still better than me attempting to implement my own `dot`. I expect the authors of ndarray have significantly better appreciation of optimisation in this regard than me, like the authors of `numpy` for broadcasting exposed custom types.

Comment: I don't know what you want me to say here. Open an issue on `ndarray`. But I wouldn't hold my breath that a linear algebra library will start supporting strings.